# Linux: if LXDE + Gnome desktops are installed, are their services running at the same time?

Tags: linux, gnome, services, lxde

Just the question of the title:

If i have in my favourite distro two different desktops installed, lets say: LXDE and Gnome at the same time, are their own services running at the same time if i'm working in only one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by "their own services". If you mean:

- desktop managers processes themselves - usually only one desktop manager is running at a time but nothing stops you from starting another desktop manager inside separate X session in another tty and have 2 desktop managers, not only 2 instances of the same desktop manager but 2 different desktop managers running simultaneously next to each other.
- services that you added to be started automatically when desktop manager starts - again it depends on where you added them. If you added to them to a particular desktop manager config they will be started only if this particular desktop manager is started but if you added them to a file such as ~/.xinitrc they will be started in all desktop managers
- GUI libraries and set of programs that are developed by the same teams that develop desktop managers, for example Koffice or programs using EFL - they will work on any desktop manager as long as you have all dependencies installed. You can run EFL programs in KDE and KDE programs in Enlightenment. But these are not "services", they do don't run in background all the time, they are loaded only where they are needed.